# Issue with result of ddply on the data frame - R

Tags: r, plyr

So I have a data frame, say with following data:

```
    Count    Amount    Org         Bank
------------------------------------------
      1        100      ABC       Chase
      15        76       DEF    American Express
    ...
    ...
```

When I run the `ddply` using:

```
result1 <- ddply(df, 4, count = sum(as.numeric(df[[1]])), amt = sum(as.numeric(df[[2]])))
```

I get the result with `result1` having the same value (i.e. `count` and `amt`) for all rows i.e.

```
 description      count        amt
  Chase             900        432087
  American Express  900        432087
.....
```

which is definitely not the case. Somehow, it seems like the last `sum()` value being calculated is applied to all the rows. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you do `dput(head(df))` to create and post a reproducible example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. **You are gettting the same/wrong result** because you are referring back to the original dataframe `df` in the arguments to ddply - e.g. `df[[1]]`.
   Ddply doesn't work like that - use column names directly, e.g. `Amount` and `Count`.
2. You are missing the `.fun` function argument to ddply - in this case `summarize` is appropriate.
   *(I honestly don't know how your code worked at all without this.)*
3. You are using an undocumented way (`4`) to select group columns in the `.variable` argument.  Try `.(Bank)` or `c("Bank")` instead.

This should work:

```
ddply(df, .(Bank), summarize, count = sum(as.numeric(Count)),
                              amt = sum(as.numeric(Amount)))
```

Comment: Is it possible to group the values of `Bank` ignoring the case i.e. right now, on applying `ddply`, the result would have separate entries for say 'Chase' and 'CHASE'. Is it possible to group entries like these in `ddply`?

Comment: You should transform the bank labels, Using (e.g.) `toupper`